# What is the procedure if your question is answered in a comment?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, comments

One of my questions got answered in a comment. What do I do? I could formulate it into an answer myself and write that down, or should I just leave it? Maybe delete the question even?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/964/answering-in-comments)?

Comment: [Closely related](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7494/using-comments-as-answers), if not a duplicate.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty ah, good find. I think that's a duplicate but we can reopen this if we decide it's not.

Comment: @DavidZ yes that answers my question